# Renderless Vue component with a click listener

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have read this post which goes in depth about renderless components:

https://adamwathan.me/renderless-components-in-vuejs/

A renderless component would pretty much look like this:

```
export default {
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({})
  },
}
```

Now I would like to use this renderless component but also add a click listener to whatever is being passed into the slot.

In my case it would be a button. My renderless component would simply wrap a button and add a click listener to it, which in turn performs an AJAX request.

How would I go about adding a click listener to the element that is being passed into the slot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to bind the click handler within the renderless component, I think from [this post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-use-the-clonevnode-methods-of-vnode/1548/4) that you need to clone the vnode passed in to `renderless`, in order to enhance it's properties.

See [createElements Arguments](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#createElement-Arguments), the second arg is the object to enhance

> A data object corresponding to the attributes you would use in a template. Optional.

```js
console.clear()
Vue.component('renderless', {
  render(createElement) {
    var vNode = this.$scopedSlots.default()[0]
    var children  = vNode.children || vNode.text
    const clone = createElement(
      vNode.tag, 
      {
        ...vNode.data, 
        on: { click: () => alert('clicked') }
      },
      children
    )
    return clone
  },
});
new Vue({}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <renderless>
    <button type="button" slot-scope="{props}">Click me</button>
  </renderless>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work in *2.6.11*, see: https://codepen.io/Livijn/pen/WNraBZo 

You need to replace `const vNode = this.$scopedSlots.default({});` with `const vNode = this.$scopedSlots.default({})[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to go about this.

Your renderless component wrapper would consist of a single `action` (i.e. the function to issue the AJAX request) prop.

```
Vue.component('renderless-action-wrapper', {
  props: ['action'],
  render() {
    return this.$scopedSlots.default({
      action: this.action,
    });
  },
});
```

Then another component which uses the aforementioned wrapper would enclose a customisable slot with a `@click` handler, which invokes the action that is passed in when triggered.

```
Vue.component('clickable', {
  props: ['action'],
  template: `
    <renderless-action-wrapper :action="action">
      <span slot-scope="{ url, action }">
        <span @click="action()">
          <slot name="action"></slot>
        </span>
      </span>
    </renderless-action-wrapper>
  `,
});
```

Finally, wire up the specialised version of the wrapper.

```
<clickable :action="doAjaxRequest">
  <button type="button" slot="action">Button</button>
</clickable>
```

[Here's a live example of the above suggestion you can play around with.](http://plnkr.co/edit/MBXrk7?p=preview)